# Finding length of hypotenuse T

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I have the question:

[image]

And I am asked to find the tension, T, in the rope.

I have drawn a triangle:

[image]

And have tried to use trigonometry to find T. However, the solutions say that T should be 17.8N and I am not sure how this is achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that the bar is **attached** to the wall at $A$, so it will not slide up or down.  So the only thing needed for equilibrium is that the net torque about point $A$ balance to zero.

The torque due to the bar weight is 
$$
\tau_b = 20 \mbox{ N} \cdot 0.4 \mbox{ m} = 8 \mbox{ N-m}
$$

The torque due to the tension of the rope is 
$$
\tau_r = T_y \cdot 0.7 \mbox{ m}
$$
where $T_y$ is the upward component of the force exerted by the rope
$$
T_y = T\sin(40^\circ)
$$
Solving 
$$
T\sin(40^\circ) \cdot  0.7 \mbox{ m}= 8 \mbox{ N-m}\\
T = \frac{8}{0.7 \sin(40^\circ)} \frac{\mbox{ N-m}}{\mbox{ m}}\approx 17.78 \mbox{ N}
$$

Comment: Could I just ask where you got 0.4 m from ? (:

Answer (score 1):

You need to balance the torques on the bar around $A$.  The weight of the bar acts at the CG, giving a clockwise torque of ???.  The rope has to supply a counterclockwise torque to counteract this.

Comment: I kind of understand. Could you please elaborate ? And is the clockwise torque the same as the anti - clockwise torque ? (:

Comment: The magnitudes are the same but the signs are opposite.  The sum is then zero which is the condition for equilibrium.  Where are you having trouble computing the torques?